# How do I make the images and the videos at the bottom the same size?

Tags: html, css, resize, size, height

Live: https://luffydrank.github.io/FreeCodeCamp-Product-Landing-Page/

Repo: https://github.com/LuffyDrank/FreeCodeCamp-Product-Landing-Page
The images and the videos has the same class but they have different height, idk why is it not working, help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property on the video tag

> object-fit: fill

it will stretch the video to fill all the spaces on the video container so make the same height with the image

Comment: It still remains the same, it seems like it wants to maintain the aspect ratio, the width changes but not the height

Comment: I played around with it a little bit and it seems to work with something like 500px and 500px and with 50vw 50vh, but not with something like 50% 50%, and that made it work with the vw and vh, thank you